# How to share constant in different controllers and models and view in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best practice to share an global variable

eg: host = test123.com

and I Can use "host"  every where ?

I will used it as CONSTANT to show my email in many places,

So I don't want to hardcode my email address everywhere!

Thanks~

Comment: Is this going to be used as a constant or a global variable? Variables are subject to change, constants aren't.

Answer (score 2):

I will typically create a file in my `initializer` directory or add to my environment (devel or production) and declare my variable with caps.

```
production.rb

SECRET_KEY = "blahblah"
```

Then across my app, I can reference to this variable by using the `ENV`

So, in my view, I would type `ENV["SECRET_KEY"]` or just `SECRET_KEY`

Answer (score 1):

You should really avoid doing this. That being said, `::HOST = 'test123.com'`

Answer (score 0):

> I will used it as CONSTANT to show my email in many places,

if you are only using this for display purposes - then consider putting it in en.yml file (and other locale files if desired)

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-translations

Answer (score 0):

Just check this out http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file . This is the standard way of defining global configurations in Rails app.